# Why won't Flow deduce the type of a function based on what it returns?

Tags: typescript, flowtype

I was expecting this code to type check [in Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjOA7AzgFzCjAC4wAKAQ2wE8BKMAXgD4wA3OASwBMmKAPBizBY8cGAFMAdPADm5QQG5UbSgCcwOAMIxOGANakK5Iaw48GAH2OmwABTVwAtp1wSAPOe7M6y7boM+EyZWKHIAIgALTnDfIA) as it does [in TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20f%20%3D%20(x)%20%3D%3E%20console.log(x)%3B%0D%0Avar%20onClick%20%3A%20(()%20%3D%3E%20void)%20%7C%20(()%20%3D%3E%20Promise%3Cvoid%3E)%3B%0D%0AonClick%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20f(%22hi%22)%3B):

```
var onClick : (() => void) | (() => boolean);
onClick = () => { return true; }
```

Instead, I get this error:

```
4: onClick = () => { return true; }
             ^ function. Could not decide which case to select
3: var onClick : (() => void) | (() => boolean);
                  ^ union type
```

Is there a general name for this design decision, and what is the reasoning behind it?

Is it possible to ask the Flow checker to infer the return type of a function from return statements?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but why not do `(() => Promise<void>|void)`?

Comment: they mean different things: `() => A | B` is a single function that sometimes returns `A` and other times returns `B`, while `(() => A) | (() => B)` is either a function that always returns `A` or a function that always returns `B`.

Comment: e.g. hover over the call in line 5 here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20f%20%3D%20(x)%20%3D%3E%20console.log(x)%3B%0D%0Avar%20onClick%20%3A%20(()%20%3D%3E%20void)%20%7C%20(()%20%3D%3E%20Promise%3Cvoid%3E)%3B%0D%0AonClick%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20f(%22hi%22)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AonClick()%3B

Comment: You're right, I didn't fully think that through before posting, sorry :P

Answer (score 4):

You will need to either provide an explicit cast, e.g.:

```
type FuncV = () => void;
type FuncB = () => boolean;
var onClick : FuncV | FuncB;

onClick = (() => { return true; }: FuncB);
```

Or use an existential type, e.g.:

```
type Func<T: (void | string)> = () => T;
var f: Func<*>;

f = () => { return "hello"; };
var msg = f() + " world!";  // type checks against return value above
```

Comment: I know there's ways to work around. Curious why this was chosen, as it seems like a big difference between TS and Glow that I hadn't seen mentioned.

Comment: Good addition / edit! Still curious about the details and reasoning, but these workarounds will have to do :-)

Comment: Wait a sec, that's the same as `f: () => (void | string)`. d'oh!

Comment: It's not the same. But, it also accepts `f: () => (void | string)`.

Comment: How is it not the same? it's `() => T` where `T` is `(void | string)`.

Comment: It might be `(void | string)`. But it can also be `void` or `string`. For example: `f = () => { }; var msg = f() + " world!";` causes error because `f` is a function that returns nothing (`T` is `void`).

Comment: Right. I think I would prefer it be `void` or `string` and not `void | string`. is that possible?

Comment: @AndreyFedorov I think you will need to stick with the explicit cast.